# Can I delete files in folder C:\FusionLog

Tags: hard-drive, storage-spaces

On my Windows Server I found folder C:\FusionLogs that occupies a lot of Gigabytes on my disk. Can I delete files from this folder to obtain freee disk space?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, and if you don't care about the logs, you can [disable the logging](https://gist.github.com/jpluimers/2f2e3acdd53a2d6b9ec0) functionality.

Logs is there to provide a trail when shit hits the fan tho...

Comment: Thank you. Are there any other folders I can clean up?

Comment: I don't know your server.